# how do I SET the size of the ScrollView content?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Now that ScrollView ContentSize property is readonly how do I SET
the size of the ScrollView content?
That very same property that is settable in UIScrollView
(but not in xamarin forms)

I have this:

```
  <ScrollView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              x:Name="attachmentScroller"
              >
    <StackLayout x:Name="AttachmentsView" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Fill"/>
  </ScrollView>
```

what I've tried is setting AttachmentsView.MinimumWidthRequest to the desired contentWidth;
But that does not seem to expand the parent's scrollview content width
to the desired value.

Comment: I almost always use a relative layout if I'm trying to dictate the exact size that I want something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the set of the content size, by setting the property of the content, instead of the the ScrollView.

Here's it in xaml

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout HeightRequest="100" />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: For some reason it's not honored. I'm setting WidthRequest to 360 then add an element and print the Width after that: it's clipped to 320 (scrollview bounds width on that ios device)

Answer (score 1):

To stop the scroll view restricting the size of the contained content to its own size, ensure you set

ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" or "Both" or "Vertical" respectively.

i.e. for your example -

```
 <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" 
     Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
     x:Name="attachmentScroller">

 <StackLayout WidthRequest="1000" x:Name="AttachmentsView"
     Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Fill"/>

 </ScrollView>
```