# Xamarin iOS scrollview content size automatic

Tags: ios, xamarin, scrollview

I want to make a dynamic scrollview content size in Xamarin IOS. This is [my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rdUn.png).

How Can I do it ?
My scrollview take **all my view**

Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I SET the size of the ScrollView content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872540/how-do-i-set-the-size-of-the-scrollview-content)

Comment: I'm using iOS, not android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948904/calculating-contentsize-for-uiscrollview-when-using-auto-layout

Comment: Thanks for answer but it works even if my collectionView has a dynamic a height ?